# Prove that composition of any two elements from $L(f)$ is in $L(f)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $L(V)=\{f:V\to V|f \text{ is linear map}\}$

$h=a_0+a_1x+..+a_nx^n$

the value of polynomial $h(x)$ on $f\in L(V)$ is defined like this

$h(f)=a_01_V+a_1f+a_2f^2+...+a_nf^n$

where $f^n=f\circ f^{n-1}$

$\beta_f:R[X]\to L(V)$ which is linear.Let $Im(\beta_f)=L(f)$.$L(f)$ is subspace of $L(V)$

Now the part that I have hard time understanding is this.Composition of any two elements from $L(f)$  is in $L(f)$

Book says that this follows from $\beta_f(h_1h_2)=\beta_f(h_1)\circ\beta_f(h_2)$

or which is same as $(h_1h_2)(f)=h_1(f)\circ h_2(f)$

can you explain how author got this?I know that $f_1\circ(f_2+f_3)=(f_1\circ f_2)+(f_1\circ f_3)$.But I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Hint: If you apply the definition of the word "linear" two or three times you're done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, $f_1, f_2\in L(f) $ and $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$

To show, $f_1+\lambda f_2\in L(f) $

As, $f_1\in L(f) $ , $\exists p(x) \in\Bbb{R}[X]$ such that $\beta_f(p(x)) =f_1$

and, $\exists q(x) \in\Bbb{R}[X]$ auch that $\beta_f(q(x)) =f_2$

Now, $f_1+\lambda f_2=\beta_f(p(x)) +\lambda \beta_f(q(x)) =\beta_f(p(x)+\lambda q(x)) $

Hence, $\exists p(x)+\lambda q(x)\in \Bbb{R}[X]$ such that

$\beta_f(p(x)+\lambda q(x)) =f_1 +\lambda f_2$

Hence, $f_1+\lambda f_2\in L(f) $

Hence, $L(f) $ is a subspace of $L(V) $

$f_1 , f_2\in L(f) $

To show, $f_1 \circ f_2\in L(f) $

$\beta_f(p(x)) =f_1$

$\beta_f(q(x)) =f_2$

Then, $f_1\circ f_2= \beta_f(p(x)) \circ \beta_f(p(x))= p(f) \circ q(f) =(pq)(f)= \beta_f(p(x)q(x))$

Hence, $\exists p(x)\cdot q(x)\in \Bbb{R}[X]$ such that

$\beta_f(p(x)\cdot q(x)) =f_1 \circ f_2$

Edit:

$p(x) =\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_i x^i$

$q(x) =\sum_{j=0}^{n} b_j x^j$

$(pq)(x) =\sum_{i=0}^{m} \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_i b_j x^{i+j}$

$(pq) (f) =\sum_{i=0}^{m} \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_i b_j f^{i+j}= \sum_{i=0}^{m} a_i f^i \sum_{j=0}^{n}  b_j f^{j}=p(f)q(f)$

Comment: Thank you @S. G but I can't understand how this answers my question?I want to show that composition of two elements in $L(f)$ is in $L(f)$

Comment: Thank you but how you got that $p(f) \circ q(f) =(pq)(f)$?This is main part that I can't understand

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{m} \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_i b_j f^{i+j}= \sum_{i=0}^{m} a_i f^i \sum_{j=0}^{n}  b_j f^{j}$ can you please explain this step?$f^{i+j}=f \circ f^{i+j-1}$

Comment: What I mean is there was composition how you transformed that into just multiplication?

Comment: $f_1 f_2 $ means composition of $f_1 $ and $ f_2$

Comment: $f^{i+j}=f^i f^j$

Comment: Ok I am in the chat

Comment: An example $p(x)=1+x , q(x) =1-x \in \Bbb{R}[X]$

and $f\in L(V) $

Then, $(pq)(x) = 1-x^2 $

$(pq)(f)=I-f^2$

$p(f) \circ q(f) =(I+f) \circ (I-f) =(I \circ I) + (f \circ I)-(I\circ f) -(f\circ f) =I-f^2$

Comment: @unit 1991 . Don't confuse by notations. When we are dealing with composition of two functions, it is often permissible to drop $\circ $ and simply write $f_1 f_2$. And it should be clear from context.

Comment: $p(x)=a_0+a_1x$

$q(x)=b_0+b_1x$


$\sum_{i=0}^1\sum_{j=0}^1a_ib_jf^{i+j}=\sum_{i=0}^1a_i(b_0f^i(f^0)+b_1f^i(f^1))$ = $\sum_{i=0}^1a_if^i\circ(b_0f^0+b_1f^1)$ using that $f^i\circ(f^0+f^1)=f^i\circ f^0+f^i \circ f^1$ and generalize with induction
is this correct?

Comment: when you expand a product of polynomials 
using the distributive property, it
does not matter whether the symbol is $ x$ or an operator $f$. Treat  $p(f) $ as a polynomial in $f$ and do the same thing that you know about polynomial.